# How to have Google Discover language different than the General Settings language?

Tags: languages, google-apps

My initial language was French but I wanted to parameter my Android smartphone (Android 8) to English. So I went to

> Settings > General Management > Language and Input > Language > English

So far so good, my phone is in English. But it automatically changed my Google Discover articles in English too (language and sources) and I can't find a way to keep it in French.

I went through Google App options:

> More > Settings > Search language : French and Search region : French

The results are still English based. And General settings don't offer to choose Discover languages.

Is there a way I can keep Google Discover in French while having my phone in English?

Comment: Did you see this? https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9507369

Comment: @beeshyams, thanks. Yes I did see it, but it isn't exactly the same topic. Your linked topic deals with "other" languages (e.g. Russian, Chinese) appearing among the "normal" language (e.g. English).